# Least complex solution connecting 20lb propane tank to 1/2" male NPT through a twin-stage regulator

Tags: propane

I have a furnace equipped with 1/2" pipe for gas supply. The protruding pipe is male npt. The 10KBtu wall furnace expects 11-13" w.c. Are there solutions out there that go from a 20lb propane tank on one end to the 1/2" npt on the other? I'll just use a 3/8" adaptor to 1/2" if needed, since it seems like everything out there is 3/8".

I want to have 10' of hose or so and a twin-stage regulator to 11" w.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The barbecue regulators are all you need with the appropriate adapter. Usually on a crimped barbecue reg the output side is a female flare fitting. So you'd need a 1/2 npt x I think 3/8 flare.